# How can I enable the memory leak tracking with FastMM in DUnit?

Tags: delphi, memory-leaks, fastmm, dunit

In the GUI test runner, the menu items for memory leak checking are 
inactive (grayed out). Is there a special switch I have not found yet to 
activate them?

Using DUnit 9.4 (from Delphi 2009 or from the sourceforge Subversion repository) and 
FastMM4.92

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You have to build your DUnit GUI-testrunner with the FASTMM and ManualLeakReportingControl directive. This will enable the memoryleak items (Take a look in GUITestRunner.pas).

Comment: More details (because it took me a while to work it out):
(1) FastMM4 must be the first unit in the "uses" section of your test project .dpr file.
(2) Remove the "." in the line {.$define ManualLeakReportingControl} in FastMM4Options.inc
(3) Add FASTMM to the test project Conditional defines (under "Directories/Conditionals" in the Project/Options...
(4) Build the project

Comment: I found documentation on setting up DUnit with FastMM in DUnit's [readme-fastmm.txt](https://sourceforge.net/p/dunit/svn/HEAD/tree/trunk/readme-fastmm.txt)